# MVC Create RSS/Atom Feed with FileResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, browser, rss, atom-feed

I try to create a RSS feed for my ASP.NET MVC 5 web site. I created some classes to create the XML with a `XmlSerializer`. I use this serializer inside a special `Result` class which is derivated from `FileResult`:

```
public class RssResult : FileResult
{
    public RssResult() : base( "application/rss+xml") { }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        var seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RssFeed));
        seri.Serialize(response.OutputStream, this.Feed);
    }

    public RssFeed Feed { get; set; }
}
```

Then I wrote an extension method for `Controller`:

```
public static RssResult RssFeed(this Controller controller, RssFeed feed, string FileDownloadName = "feed.rss")
{
    return new RssResult()
    {
        Feed = feed,
        FileDownloadName = FileDownloadName
    };
}
```

If I call an action that returns a `RssResult` Firefox and Internet Explorer asks my to download the file. But I want to see the typical reader interfaces of the browsers.

What I am doing wrong here respectively what I must change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.100).aspx) adds a `content-disposition` header that prompts the "download" in a browser.

If you have your data serialized, just return the `content-type` (e.g. `application/xml` or what you already have (`application/rss+xml`)...so either return [`Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult(v=vs.100).aspx) or  derive from `ActionResult`

See this [XMLResult example from MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/MVCContrib/ActionResults/XmlResult.cs) - note that it derives from `ActionResult` (not `FileResult`)

Hth...

Comment: Ah, that's it :)
I changed my classes so they derivate from `ContentResult`.